# How to validate against the object "in memory" versus the stored object in the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The following code works just fine on creating "channels" that have an address like emails or phones.

```
class Channel < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :contact
  belongs_to :mechanism

  validates_uniqueness_of :address
  validates_format_of :address, :with => /@/i,
    :if => :address_is_email?
  validates_format_of :address, :with => /\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d/,
    :if => :address_is_phone?

  def before_validation
    self.address = address.gsub(/[^0-9]/, "") if mechanism.designation == "sms"
  end

  def address_is_email?
    mechanism.designation == "smtp"
  end

  def address_is_phone?
    mechanism.designation == "sms"
  end
end
```

Like so:

```
>> c = Channel.create(:mechanism_id => 1, :address => 'something@someplace.com')
=> #<Channel id: 17, created_at: "2010-12-02 15:00:59", updated_at: "2010-12-02 15:00:59", mechanism_id: 1, contact_id: nil, address: "something@someplace.com", enabled: nil, time_window_id: nil>
>> c.save
=> true
```

However, if I try to change the format from one to the other after the fact, it will fail.

```
>> c.update_attributes(:address => '888.555.1212', :mechanism_id => 2)
=> false
>> c.save
=> false
```

I'm guessing that this is because the validates_format_of is going through the address_is_*? function, and reading against the format that's stored in the database (or in memory already), and NOT against the value I'm feeding it. How would I test against the new value that I'm passing (somehow) to the class when I try to do the update_attributes? The only thing I can see to do, given the code above, is delete the channel and create a new one with the different format.

Comment: Maybe there's a different validation causing problems.  What happens if you do: `c.errors.full_messages.to_sentence`?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is with this line:

```
validates_format_of :address, :with => /\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d/,
    :if => :address_is_phone?
```

The regular expression is expecting 10 digits, with nothing in between!  If you want dots, like your example above, do it like this:

```
validates_format_of :address, :with => /\d\d\d\.\d\d\d\.\d\d\d\d/,
    :if => :address_is_phone?
```

And of course, you can get as complex as you want from there.  I hope this helps!

**PS:** This is a shorter, easier to read version:

```
validates_format_of :address, :with => /\d{3}\.\d{3}\.\d{4}/,
    :if => :address_is_phone?
```

Comment: But shouldn't the before_validation gsub remove the periods... before the validation gets checked?